# Blutooth Discovery Protocol is not Working at all . cant find my device using bluetooth , ubuntu 15.04 lenovo z 50-70

Tags: bluetooth

```
godfather@godfather-Lenovo:~$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
Linux godfather-Lenovo 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    2.194525] usb 1-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    7.908843] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    7.908861] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.908866] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.908869] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.908875] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.540324] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.540327] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   21.540330] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   21.824664] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   21.824671] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   21.824676] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    0.159018] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    8.825332] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[   12.628783] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install bluetooth drivers this way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms rtl8723au-bt-dkms linux-firmware
```

Bluetooth should work after reboot.